# How do I compute speed based on acceleration and drag?

Tags: physics

I'm interested in simulating the (one-dimensional) speed and position of a car.

How can I compute the speed $v(t)$ given initial speed $v_0$, acceleration $a(t)$ (I don't want to assume that it is constant) and a drag independent of the time and dependent only of the current speed in a quadratic way, i.e., $d(t) = d_0 \cdot v^2(t)$?

I'm stuck at $v(t) = \int a(t) dt$ and don't know how I can incorporate the drag.

Comment: If your drag is proportional to the speed, can't you give the drag a constant such as say `0.98` and then multiply by ∫a(t)dt

Comment: The drag is proportional to the square of the speed.

Comment: Do you want to solve the ode $\,m \dot v=-kv^2$ ?

Comment: Basically, yes, that's it. Indeed, that simplifies it quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the question, is a(t) given?

If yes so write 
$ dV/dt+d_1V^2=a(t)$

now if a(t) is a constant you can separate variables and get
$dV/(a(t)+d1_V^2)=dt$ and do integration from $V_0$ to V and $t=0$  to t  [here is the answer](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1/%28a-d%2ax%5E2%29&random=false) 
$V(0)=V_0, d_1=d_0/M$
M=mass of body

Comment: Yes, $a(t)$ is given. I could work with a constant acceleration $a(t) = a_0$ for a start. But I still don't get how I go from your answer to a formula for $v(t)$?

Comment: And then integrate $v(t) = \int a(t) - d_1v(t)^2 \mathrm{d}t$, which can be hard, depending on $a$. Or are you simulating on a computer?

Comment: Actually, it's a differential equation, then. Assume the acceleration is constant. How do I go about solving it?

Comment: Assuming the acceleration is constant, it is $v(t)=v_0+at$  If the acceleration is given, for this purpose you would just use timesteps:  $v(t+\Delta t)=v(t)+ a(t)(\Delta t)$  That is the Euler method for doing the integral.  It allows you to calculate $a(t)$ as you go, maybe based on player input.  The drag just becomes one piece of calculating $a(t)$